# Store file if user confirms it

Tags: python, html, django, mongodb

I am quite new to Django. Here is the issue I am having now.
User will upload some data and file in a django form. But the data including file will not be uploaded unless user confirms it. Here is the flow:

1. user enters some data and selects a file for upload
2. the file will be viewed (the content of the file) to the user
3. if user wills to upload that file only then the file will be uploaded else it will not upload to database.

I hope that I can get some suggestions/ways of doing it. Having a tough time with it. Thank you for understanding

Comment: What sort of file are we talking about?

Comment: .txt file. normal text files

Comment: Then use the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader API to read the file selected by the user before it is uploaded.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.